# Calculate NEF of an amplifier

Tags: power, amplifier, noise

Can anyone help me how I can find the NEF(noise efficient factor) from a low noise -low power amplifier in ADS (Advance Design System) software design? I have searched a lot but I can't find how I can measure it through the software.

Comment: What does the instruction manual suggest? Or call the magazine "Microwave System News" and chat with one of their editors.

Comment: I did not find any clarification in a manual about NEF

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that ADS has a built in tool for measuring NEF. You'll need the equation for calculating the NEF (noise efficiency factor) and will need to compute it by entering the equation into ADS. This is usually done in the data display window.

I found the equation describing NEF in a [paper by Somak and Hall](http://bioee.ucsd.edu/papers/An%20ECG%20Chopper%20Amplifier%20Achieving%200.92%20NEF%20and%200.85%20PEF%20with%20AC-coupled%20Inverter%20Stacking%20for%20Noise%20Efficiency%20Enhancement%20-%20Hall%20(ISCAS,%202017).pdf), see equation 1. It appears that NEF is a function of the input referred noise which is described in equation 3.